# C# string.Format 1000,00 to 1.000,00

Tags: c#, string, string.format

How can I change Numbers to the following:

`1000` should become `1.000,00`, when I have `700`, it has to be `700,00`.
When I try `string.Format("{0:0,000.00}", Number)`, `700` becomes `0.700,00`, so it's not good.

Comment: You want the decimal seperator to be , and the thousands separator to be .?

Comment: @AseemGautam - That's how it works in several cultures in our little planet.

Comment: Try # instead or 0? {0:#.###,00}. Also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: Check my answer. You can do this at application level. Saves a lot of work, plus doing it at a zillion places in code is just maintenance hell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need

```
string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", Number)
```

You need to specify the lead placeholder as a # rather than a zero, which makes it optional.

However, rather than "brute force" to set the number format, it may be better to work out which culture's format you are aiming for and supply the correct `CultureInfo` to the string.format. `String.Format` lets you supply the culture for formatting as follows:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
var formattedNumber = string.Format(culture , "{0:n}", Number);
```

(I chose to use French purely as an illustration and because it seems to match the requirements in your examples).

What you shouldn't do, is use `{0:n}` without specifying the culture if you care about having a specific format - as this is entirely dependent on the culture settings of the user/system.

Comment: The most common pattern is `#,##0.00`. Will produce `0,01` and `1.000.000,00`

Comment: @Xeramal - Use `de-DE` in that case.

Comment: The culture "de-DE" may be what you need!

Answer (score 6):

Supply the proper `CultureInfo` in the [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You want the decimal seperator to be , and the thousands separator to be .

Best way is to define this at application level for consistency.

**Winforms:**

In program.cs

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
```

**ASP.NET**

Define a base page, and do:

```
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
    base.InitializeCulture(); 

     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";    
     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";                    
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When formatting a number using a format string, the `.` is a *placeholder* for whatever the decimal separator is for the culture being used for formatting. The `,` is similarly used as the thousands separator.

You need to use these in their correct place and use a culture that uses a `,` for a decimal separator and `.` for a thousands separator.

```
string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), "{0:n}", 1000)
```

Produces `1.000,00`.

```
string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"), "{0:n}", 1000)
```

Produces `1,000.00`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try setting the NumberFormat as per your need

```
NumberFormatInfo num = new NumberFormatInfo();

num.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
num.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
string samp =  70000.00.ToString("N2",num); // prints 70.000,00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this    `String.Format("{0:n}", 1000 )`

Comment: NO!! - this makes it entirely dependent on the current culture settings. Try this as a different user with different locale settings, and you'll get different answers. This is *not* the correct way to force a format to a specific thing.

Comment: @RobLevine i agree ! , im not sure may Xeramal go to that extend

Answer (score 0):

Try `String.Format("#,0.##")`. It works for me.
Input: 800
Output: 800,00

Input: 1400
Output: 1.400,00

I use a German culture for the number format. Maybe you have to specify it, depending on your culture.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
NumberFormatInfo num = new CultureInfo("de-DE", false).NumberFormat;
double myDigit = 123456789; // you can also use int
string output = myDigit.ToString("N0" , num);
//output = 123.456.789
```

if you use `ToString("F" , num)` you can use `123456789.33` and your output will be `123.456.789,33`